# How to understand this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am a English learner. When I read an article in English, some sentences are confused me. Can anyone explains the sentences for me?

The whole paragraph I have questions is below:

> More than 750,000 have graduated from the Space and Aviation Center(SAC), with many seeking employment in engineering, aviation, education, medicine and a wide variety of other professions. They come to camp, wanting to know what it is like to be an astronaut or a pilot, and they leave with real-world applications for what they're studying in the classroom.

There are two sentences I am confusing:

1) *More than 750,000 have graduated from SAC, with many seeking employment in engineering*...

I got stucks on "with many seeking employment". Does this sentence mean over 750,000 students have graduated from SAC and they are looking for a job in engineering, aviation, education...? Or it means these students who graduated from SAC do have job but they want to know what it is like to be an astronaut or a pilot?

2) ...*they leave with real-world applications for what they're studying in the classroom*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your initial interpretation is correct, i.e., 'over 750,000 students have graduated from SAC and (many of them) are looking for a job in engineering, aviation, education...'

2) This sentence means that many students come to SAC with dreams of being an astronaut or a pilot. Many of them are, or will be, taking academic courses in aerospace engineering, or similar disciplines. However, they don't have enough practical knowledge of what they will be required to do within the aerospace industry when they graduate. Attending the camp at SAC gives these students some hands-on, practical experience, so they have a better idea how they will apply the theoretical concepts that they are learning.

Comment: `and many are seeking employment` means that is a *subset* of the 750,000 graduates, not all 750,000. In a Venn diagram, the `seeking employment` circle fits inside the `750,000 graduate` circle.

Comment: @ DrMoishe Pippik  Absolutely.  The use of many (as opposed to some, a few, all), indicates that a large number of those 750,000 graduates are seeking employment in this sector, probably the majority of them, but certainly not all of them.